# Отображение страниц с видеороликами через QWebView

Tags: webkit, html, qt, c++, html5

Здравствуйте! Нужно отображение страниц с видеороликами через `QWebView`. В Windows тег video просто игнорируется. Собирал с Qt 4.8.1, 4.8.2, 5.0. Везде одинаково. На Linux проблем нет.

Подскажите, в чем может быть проблема. Если WebKit не в состоянии мне помочь, буду благодарен если кто тыкнет носом в инфу как заюзать `gecko`.

Comment: А этот сэмпл http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/HTML5_video_player_app_using_a_QWebView
тоже не работает?

Comment: Не работает((( Не думаю что кодеки... В других браузерах работает. Пробовал на разных компах. Примеры из Qt Examples and Demos тоже не воспроизводят.

Comment: Итак. В Qt SDK 4.8 QtWebkit из коробки собран без поддержки аудио/видео. С чего бы? 
Попытка собрать QtWebkit с параметром --video не дает результата.Все зависимости установлены. Вылетает на этапе компиляции класса MediaPlayer. На сколько я понимаю ей не хватает какого то мультимедиа фреймворка. Хотя Phоnon работает без проблем.
В 4,8,3 ситуация не изменилась.
В 4,7,4 видео работает но там старая версия QtWebkit, а мне нужно побольше поддержки HTML5. Попытка сборки QtWebkit 2,2 с Qt 4,7,4 приводит к тому же что и с 4.8.


Кто то знает чего ему не хватает?

Answer (score 1):

Кодеки всё равно надо ставить. Лучше всего k-lite, т.к. скопом сразу все и надёжно. То, что эксплорер показывает видео, так он использует для этого имеющиеся у него внутри кодеки, которые недоступны для использования другими приложениями.